# Java JDT detecting simple statements

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

Let's say variable i is initialized like:

```
int i = 0;
```

I'm trying to detect simple java variable changes like:

```
i=i+1;
```

This can be done using a visitor pattern with JDT like:

```
public boolean visit(XXXXXXX node) {

   //something here


}
```

However, I'm not sure of the name of XXXXX that will give me the statement in the second code example. I've looked through http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FASTNode.html but it is really big and so far I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"i = i + 1" is an `ExpressionStatement` (your XXXXXXX). The expression inside is of type `Assignment` where you can check the operator, `SimpleName` of the left hand side and the `InfixExpression` on the right hand side.

A great tool to analize your code is the ASTView. It can show you the AST of any code marked in your editor. You can install it into Eclipse from the update site http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/update-site

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a setter to achieve similar results?

```
int i = 0;

public void setI(int _i) {
    this.i = _i;
    // execute visit() code here
}

setI(i++);
```

While I do not know the context for which you need to monitor variable value changes, this seems like a quick alternative.

Comment: The i+1 etc code is just an example. The program should be able to run on any code that is defined as X = Y +/-/*/etc Z. In otherwords any variable changes such as string s; String s = "" + "hi";